# Do you know any MySQL (web based) online clients?

Tags: mysql

Do you know any online (web based) MySQL clients ?

I mean an application that allows me to login to a remote MySQL server. (A third-party web hosted installation that allows me to specify the IP, username and password of my MySQL server.)

Comment: superuser is for computer hardware and software related questions **only**. Websites are considered **off topic** as defined by the site scope laid out in the [FAQ](http://superuser.com/faq).

Answer (score 3):

[phpMyAdmin](http://www.phpmyadmin.net/home_page/index.php) is a free software tool written in PHP intended to handle the administration of MySQL over the World Wide Web. phpMyAdmin supports a wide range of operations with MySQL. The most frequently used operations are supported by the user interface (managing databases, tables, fields, relations, indexes, users, permissions, etc), while you still have the ability to directly execute any SQL statement.

phpMyAdmin comes with a wide range of documentation and users are welcome to update our wiki pages to share ideas and howtos for various operations. The phpMyAdmin team will try to help you if you face any problem, you can use variety of support channels to get help.

phpMyAdmin is also very deeply documented in a book written by one of developers – Mastering phpMyAdmin for Effective MySQL Management, which is available in English, Czech, German and Spanish.

To ease usage to a wide range of people, phpMyAdmin is translated into 58 languages and supports both LTR and RTL languages.

phpMyAdmin is a more than ten years old project with stable and flexible code base

Comment: I know, but i couldn't find any web hosted installation what allow me to use IP of my mysql server, username and password.

I'm looking for testing tool using World Wide Web.
That test tool should be working on my hosting, or can be hosted anywhere in the web.

But at loogin page should ask me a 3 question
Host: 98.124.687.21
Username:xxx
Password:xxx



Any idea ?

Comment: @marc: can you not download and install phpMyAdmin on your server?

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to phpMyAdmin (as suggested by Nifle) is [Adminer](http://www.adminer.org/), basically a lightweight phpMyAdmin in one file.